# What do these arrows in design pattern diagrams mean?

Tags: terminology, software-engineering

I am learning about software design patterns by reading Wikipedia pages about them. A lot of the patterns such as the bridge pattern have diagrams with boxes and different kinds of arrows:

[image]
<sup>Source: [Wikipedia](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cf/Bridge_UML_class_diagram.svg/500px-Bridge_UML_class_diagram.svg.png)</sup>

Do these diagrams stem from a standard? Why do some arrows have different ending markings? Also, why are some of them dotted?

Comment: Look a the name of the file: evidently, it's a UML class diagram.  Google for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ConcreteImplementer inherits from Implementer, 
Same for RefinedAbstraction and Abstraction

The other arrow: these classes composes without belonging to each other.

See also [here](http://www.ivencia.com/softwarearchitect/chapter1/chapter1_6.htm).

The paper-like box is a note (a comment).

Comment: Perhaps also mention that its UML? Is it UML?

Comment: Yes, this is UML.

Answer (score 4):

The arrows mean distinct things. This is a UML (unified modeling language) diagram. Rules for reading and writing these diagrams are pretty well-established, and you should be able to look up some references.

In that diagram, the hollow arrow means generalization (i.e., inheritance, IS_A), and the hollow diamond means aggregation (i.e., a kind of association, HAS_A). The dotted line connects a comment/label and contains auxiliary/meta information (I believe, but double check this one).